# Select more columns along with two counts with group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to come up with a solution that lists almost all the columns of a table along with count of two columns grouped by two different fields, that I can use to create two dashboards with count filtered by Entity and Type.

Something like below.

```
select c.Entity,C.Type,C.TestID,C.a,C.b,C.x,C.y,C.z,
       count (TESTID) as CountbyEntity,
       count (TESTID) as CountbyType
from Testplan c group by Entity, Type
```

I would like to include the below two queries to the rest of the columns without having to use a separate SQLs.

```
select count (TESTID) as CountbyType,Type 
from TESTPLAN 
where Type is not null 
group by Type

select count (TESTID) as CountbyEntity,Entity 
from TESTPLAN 
where Entity is not null 
group by Entity
```

Comment: Please provide us with some example data.

Comment: `sum(case when condition then 1 else 0 end)`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you shoud use `count() over(partition by)` instead of `group by`:

```
select c.Entity,C.Type,C.TestID,C.a,C.b,C.x,C.y,C.z,
       count (TESTID) over(partition by Entity) as CountbyEntity,
       count (TESTID) over(partition by Type) as CountbyType
from Testplan c
```

for more information, read [Analytic functions by Example](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55) blog post.

Comment: Count by Type Type
2 Type1
7 Type2
1 Type3
2 Type4
2 Type5


Count by Entity Entity
5 Entity 1
3 Entity 2
3 Entity 3
2 Entity 4
1 Entity 5

The result I am looking for looks something like above, if I use partition, the dashboard displays Entity 1 5 times. Maybe I need to use separate queries  to achieve this as the dashboard is not sophisticated enough to weed out the repeated entity names. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you could provide sample data as ddl+dml and desired results it would probably help...